# Sending @Published variable as both value and Publisher

Tags: swift, combine

Is there a way to pass a `@Published` variable as parameter to a function that needs access to both the current value of the variable and listen to any changes to the value?

Sample code:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class Player {
    @Published var progress = 0
}

class PlayerHandler {
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    func send(progress: Int, progressPublisher: Published<Int>.Publisher) {
        print("Do something with current progress: \(progress)")

        cancellable = progressPublisher.sink {
            progr in
            print("Do something else with: \(progr)")
        }
    }
}

let handler = PlayerHandler()
let player = Player()
handler.send(progress: player.progress, progressPublisher: player.$progress)//Can I send this variable only once?
player.progress = 1
player.progress = 2
```

Here, I pass the `progress` variable as both an `Int` and as a `Published<Int>.Publisher`. Is there a way to pass the variable only once? How can I do that?

(I know, I could have used a `CurrentValueSubject` instead of a `@Published` variable, but I really like being able to access `progress` directly as allowed by @Published, instead of having to use `progress.value`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Published.Publisher` emits the current value when a subscription is created to it.

So you don't need to pass in the current value manually, you'll get that when calling `sink` on the `Published.Publisher`.

If you want to handle the current value and subsequent value changes differently, you can create a `Bool` flag, which you set to `true` once the first value is emitted by the `Publisher` and do the appropriate processing based on the value of this flag.

```
class PlayerHandler {
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var didProcessFirstValue: Bool = false

    func send(progressPublisher: Published<Int>.Publisher) {
        cancellable = progressPublisher.sink { progr in
            if !self.didProcessFirstValue {
                print("Do something with initial progress: \(progr)")
                self.didProcessFirstValue = true
            } else {
                print("Do something else with: \(progr)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it is so. Thanks for guiding me!
In my case, I needed to pass the publisher further down, but I needed the current value (in order to send this to the server) before passing the publisher on to another function. I obtained this by:
`player.$progress.prefix(1).sink {
    print("send latest value: \($0) to server")
};
print("ready to pass on progress to another function")
`